# How to get the rows with none values in R

Tags: r, select, null

I'm learning R now.So i have a question. I use the the titanic dataset.Now i want to get the rows with none or null values by column Embarked.
The dataset is like that with column Embarked. And we have 2 rows with None value by Embarked

```
  :  2   
 C:168   
 Q: 77   
 S:644
```

i tried with this

```
titanic[titanic$Embarked==""]
```

i got this error

Error in `[.data.frame`(titanic, titanic$Embarked == "") :
undefined columns selected.

Could someone help me this one.Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: the missing values are probably NA, you could try: `titanic[is.na(titanic$Embarked),]` , dont forget the final comma in the brackets

Answer (score 1):

For the 2 rows:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(titanic)

titanic_train |> 
  filter(Embarked == "")
#>   PassengerId Survived Pclass                                      Name    Sex
#> 1          62        1      1                       Icard, Miss. Amelie female
#> 2         830        1      1 Stone, Mrs. George Nelson (Martha Evelyn) female
#>   Age SibSp Parch Ticket Fare Cabin Embarked
#> 1  38     0     0 113572   80   B28         
#> 2  62     0     0 113572   80   B28

OR

titanic_train[titanic_train$Embarked == "",]
#>     PassengerId Survived Pclass                                      Name
#> 62           62        1      1                       Icard, Miss. Amelie
#> 830         830        1      1 Stone, Mrs. George Nelson (Martha Evelyn)
#>        Sex Age SibSp Parch Ticket Fare Cabin Embarked
#> 62  female  38     0     0 113572   80   B28         
#> 830 female  62     0     0 113572   80   B28
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>